# ExpandableListView с меняющимися цветами

Tags: java, android, color, design, expandablelistview

Есть ExpandableListView и 2 цвета. Оно должно работать по такому принципу: должен быть родительский синий, потом дочерней красный, затем дочерний 2 синий, дочерней 3 красный, дочерней 4 синий, Родительский 2 - красный.

В зависимости от количества дочерних меняются все последующие. Должно работать при любом раскладе.

Comment: Т.е. просто отображаемые ячейки должны чередовать цвет?

Comment: да, но с учетом дочерних элементов, которые видны пользователю.

Comment: Я вроде так и сказал) Вне зависимости от того, какие группы раскрыты и сколько в них дочерних эл-тов всё отображаемое должно чередовать цвет? А что, если закрыть группу с нечётным кол-вом элементов? Последующие должны цвет сменить?

Comment: Да цвет должен поменяться.